# using NLP to complete sentences

Tags: java, android, nlp, stanford-nlp

I am working on sign language translator android application where the signs are inputted then the application will translate it to english sentence.
one problem that I am facing is that sometimes due to some error in capturing the signs correctly, the sentence formed as a result becomes ill formatted, lose some words or lose it meaning.

For Example:

> My Name is Mike

Becomes--

> My Name is Mke

or somthing like

> I am heading to school

becomes--

> I am to school

I want something to check every sentence that is entered and provide suggestion in case the sentence is not formed correctly.

I tried using Stanford CoreNLP but I couldn't find a straightforward solution to my problem.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_model

Comment: + nice basic tutorial on spelling correction: http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html